# How to made select option selected in react js / javascript

Tags: javascript, select, dropdown, html-select, queryselector

I should have dropdown with 2 options, and based on a configuration option one should be selected with an event handler in JavaScript.

I tried the below code :

```
const $select = document.querySelector('#mySelect');
$select.value = 'steve'
```

Comment: Assuming that the `value` attribute of the desired `<option>` element is "steve" (it has to be an exact match), your posted code works: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5dzv0x8L/).

Comment: @DavidThomas is correct. So I will have to assume that you are doing something else that is causing it not to work, but you are not showing us everything so we can't help.